# How do I check a checkbox when an element contains a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, input, field

I am not sure why this is not working, and am looking for some guidance.  Basically, I want the checkbox to be checked when the `span` contains the class "active", and want it not to be checked when the `span` does not contain the class "active".

What is wrong with my code?  Thank you so much in advance for the assistance!

```
<span class="option" id="website-selector"></span>

<input type="checkbox" class="website_check" />


<script type="text/javascript">             
if ( $("#website-selector").hasClass("active") ) {
    $(".website_check").prop('checked', true);
}
else {
    $(".website_check").prop('checked', false);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code seems perfectly fine! Is the script tag always below the elements like in the example? You do realize that this only runs on pageload, adding the class later does nothing?

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/LzMya/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write the function inside the document.ready :

```
<script type="text/javascript">             

   $(document).ready(function(){  
   if ( $("#website-selector").hasClass("active") ) {
   $(".website_check").prop('checked', true);
  }
   else {
       $(".website_check").prop('checked', false);
  }
});
</script>
```